# Некоторые сервера VK отдают неверные CORS заголовки

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, chrome-extension, cors

Я разрабатываю музыкальное расширение для **Google Chrome** и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Музыка ВКонтакте располагается на нескольких серверах, которые находятся в зоне
***.vk-cdn.net**

Некоторые сервера поддерживают **CORS** и таким образом я могу получить их контент по JS

> accept-ranges:bytes
>   access-control-allow-methods:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   access-control-allow-origin:*
>   cache-control:max-age=604800
>   content-length:5292838
>   content-type:audio/mpeg
>   date:Wed, 13 Jan 2016 20:32:05 GMT
>   expires:Wed, 20 Jan 2016 20:32:05 GMT
>   last-modified:Wed, 13 Jan 2016 16:45:43 GMT
>   server:nginx
>   status:200 OK
>   version:HTTP/1.1

А некоторые сервера, которые на **Apache**, не отдают этих заголовков

> Accept-Ranges:bytes
>   Cache-Control:max-age=1468800
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:655080
>   Content-Type:audio/mpeg
>   Date:Wed, 13 Jan 2016 20:34:52 GMT
>   ETag:"4b23d502-9fee8"
>   Expires:Sat, 30 Jan 2016 20:34:52 GMT
>   Last-Modified:Sat, 12 Dec 2009 17:38:10 GMT
>   Server:Apache

Таким образом, запросы к таким серверам через JS невозможны, так как Chrome c 45 версии это запретил. Получаем ошибку о том, **MediaElementAudioSource** выдает нули вместо контента, из-за **CORS**

> MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions
>   for https://psv4.vk.me/c613321/u3197020/audios/00a66935ba83.mp3

Браузер все равно проигрывает эти файлы, что меня подталкивает на мысль, что возможность получить доступ к содержимому все-таки есть.

Я пытался общаться с поддержкой ВК, но получил ответ, что на баг-трекер сайта давно забили и никто исправлять не будет это.

Можно ли как-то обойти это ограничение?

Comment: вероятно, что нельзя, иначе это было бы большой дырой в безопасности браузера.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете поставить где-нибудь свой прокси сервер, который будет проксировать аудио с серверов ВК и добавлять заголовки чтоб всё корректно работало через AJAX. Для таких целей наверно лучше всего подойдет nginx

Comment: Трафик будет нехилый :)